# How to set port forwarding to use terminal server client?

Tags: command-line, remote-control

I'm using the terminal server client in Ubuntu to connect to a Windows machine in another location but I don't get it to work. I wonder what should be the port forwarding setting so I can connect.

So far I've managed to connect to a Windows machine on the same house, but what about in another locations?

Comment: What protocol do you use? RDP or VNC?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you use RDP ([Remote Desktop Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol)), as it works out of the box in Windows.

RDP uses TCP port 3389 by default; so port forwarding needs to be set up like this:

```
port 3389 on your router --> port 3389 on your Windows machine
```

For [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) you would need to do the same, but with port 5900.

Comment: yes RDP is the one i use and now is working thanx!

Comment: @peter, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) answers which you find the most useful or solving your question.

Comment: I recommend to change the outbound port to something else like 3389, like 78974 (random). A bit more security by obscurity.